# Skip file input and use only if is necessary

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this little form:

```
<form action="?act=process" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="IMG">
  <input type="text" name="BG">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

How can I skip the file input if I want to edit only the text input?
I need both because sometimes i need to channge the image.

- I need to skip the input after POST submit. Only if the input wasn't changed

Comment: When editing, don't select a new image. Just skip it.

Comment: Skip it... when? When validating? When selecting the `input` elements? When sending a request? When saving the data? Help us to help you. No one ever got downvoted for describing what they want to have happen.

Comment: Doesn't work. The input file value is passed as empty value and modify my database.

Comment: @Rory Sory, I forgot to mention this. I need to skip the input after POST submit. Only if the IMG input wasn't changed

Comment: By _Only if the input was not changed_ Do you mean, only if the `BG` text input was not changed?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan IMG input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without seeing your PHP code for "after POST submit" I am guessing that you will simply want to code in a conditional check if the `IMG` input is empty or not before updating your database.

so it might look something like this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["IMG"]))
   // update database
```